# RGB LEDs indvidual brightness control

Tags: led, led-driver, led-strip, constant-current, led-matrix

i want to make RGB LEDs panel using https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Light-Emitting-Diodes-LED_TCWIN-TC5050RGBF08-3CJH-P35C_C784539.html RGB LEDs. I will put 100 LEDs in tha panel and want to control brightness of each led separately via ESP32 PWM. I am unable to figure out what sort of led driver should i use or how to connect leds in such a way that i can control brightness of each led separately.

Comment: You might want to use addressable LEDs since those incorporate the PWM driver into the pixel and you only have to set the brightness. Depending on the type and how you address them they can be updated relatively fast without a very complex board design.

Comment: I don't think it was fair to close this as a _use_ question, but perhaps _too broad_ since it's a lot of work doing this if you don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will put 100 LEDs in tha panel and want to control brightness of each led separately via ESP32 PWM.

100x LEDs, with 3x colors each comes to 300 PWM channels. You're not going to find many low-end parts that can drive that many PWM channels concurrently, and certainly no ESP32s!

---

Your preferred route will likely depend on how frequently you need (want) to update the display, and how concerned you are about color balance, power budgets, run-time complexity, and CPU time on the ESP32.

The most simple option is one or more strings of "*addressable RGB LEDs*" - each string requires only one or two signals from the controller, and each LED has a controller built in to deal with the communication, chaining, and maintain the set brightness.

Another option is to employ a number of separate parts, each dedicated to a small group of LEDs... "*LED drivers*" exist with up to 32 channels from a single package (possibly more), meaning that you'd require around 10x of these (or more, depending on channel count per IC). They'll likely also maintain the set brightness, will probably have lower quiescent current, and may have some nicer features (e.g: higher / configurable PWM frequency).

You're heading into "*LED matrix*" territory here, the schematics for which are widely available. They typically split up the R/G/B channels into serial streams (using shift registers), addressing the LEDs in a column / row scheme... they shift out the bits (on/off) for each column of the display's full width, and then strobe a single line, repeating this very quickly to "*scan*" the whole display, forever - keeping the display "*refreshed*" relies on doing it fast enough (i.e: persistence of vision) and requires constantly flashing each row one at a time, no stopping. Achieving 8 colors (Black, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Cyan, Magneta, White) is fairly straightforward, but as the bit-depth increases, so does the work involved, along with the signalling speeds.